# Getting error 1054 when trying to add a record to a table (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, insert

There is a user table, it has many fields, but NOT NULL and only 3 without default value (login, password, email). All three types of varchar. I am trying to add a record with the query:

```
INSERT INTO user (login, password, email) VALUES ('Den', '12345', 'test@mail.ru');
```

I get:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'login' in 'field list' The field exists, called 'login'.

When the request is changed to:

```
INSERT INTO user (password, email) VALUES ('12345', 'test@mail.ru');
```

I get (logical):

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'login' doesn't have a default value

Everything happens in MySQL Workbench. I don't understand what the problem is, if the field exists and I write the name correctly

Also previously I renamed the column from Name to Login

if I return the name to the name, then everything works

---

**UPDATE**

```sql
CREATE TABLE user ( 
    id bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Первичный ключ', 
    login varchar(15) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Логин пользователя', 
    password varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Пароль пользователя', 
    email varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Электронная почта пользователя', 
    phone varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Телефон пользователя', 
    address varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Адрес пользователя', 
    birth_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01' COMMENT 'Дата рождения пользователя', 
    registration_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01' COMMENT 'Дата регистрации пользователя', 
    is_admin tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Роль пользователя. True(1) - администратор, False(0) - клиент.', 
    is_banned tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    user_status_id tinyint unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE KEY login_UNIQUE (login), 
    UNIQUE KEY email_UNIQUE (email), 
    UNIQUE KEY phone_UNIQUE (phone) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='Таблица пользователей'
```

Comment: *Also previously I renamed the column from Name to Login* Have you committed this change?

Comment: Akina, yes (Да) by executing script (auto genereted in workbench)

Comment: Can you test the same using CLI? And look for `SHOW CREATE TABLE user` via it? Also check does current database is selected correctly (or specify it in the query explicitly).

Comment: Akina, database selected with USE databaseName;
In CLI it works perfect.

Comment: If so this is (some strange) client issue... does used Workbench version matched to MySQL version? try to remove and reinstall it...

Comment: Akina, yes they matches both, version 8.0
I already have removed and reinstalled it again
SHOW CREATE TABLE link to image in description of question (topic)

Comment: *SHOW CREATE TABLE link to image in description of question (topic)* Provide it as textual copy, not as image.

Comment: Akina, I cannot print it in comment, becouse of it's length is too large, so I'll leave it in the answer to the question below you can see it

Comment: I tries to reproduce your issue a lot of times without success. I'd recommend to backup the data then drop and re-create the table.

Comment: Akina, Restarting mysql work bench solved the problem, but I really don't know won't it happen again
Anyway, thank you very much